# Link to a specific panel of an accordion

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question concerning the folowing webpage: http://www.dekoninck.be/en/visit-us/the-experience

In the middle of the page their is an accordion with 3 panels:

- Tastings
- Workshop
- Coffee reception

I need a link to this page (url) that goes to the second panel (workshop) and opens it.
I tried

- .../the-experience#works
- .../the-experience?accordion#workshop_active

and a number of variations but nothing works.

The only thing that seems to work is

- .../the-experience#accordion

but that only links to the accordion not to the specific panel...

I’m not the developer of this site, I’m responsible for the adcampaigns and I need this link for a specific campaign.
I could ask the developer but I’m afraid to look stupid :-)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Valerie

Comment: You can't, that accordion toggles classes via Javascript, so the only way to show the second panel is to actually click it

Comment: If the accordion script used does not natively offer this functionality, then it’ll have to be implemented on top of that. And that’s the part where you go ask your developer :)